# mobile flex, know the source location

Tags: android, apache-flex, mobile, geolocation

I'm developing a flex mobile application and need to take data from lat/long, I'm doing tests on a smartphone with android and I saw that there are two ways to get the lat/long, Coarse Location (WiFi/Cell-ID) and Fine Location (GPS satellites).

Is there any way to know what kind of source location is being used?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you have access to this information, other than specifying the Android permissions for fine/coarse location in the app xml file. Ie: you could only specify course location and then always know what you're dealing with (doesn't work w/fine because device may fall back to coarse location).

Instead of that, however, I would use the `horizontalAccuracy` and `verticalAccuracy` properties of the [GeolocationEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/GeolocationEvent.html).

You can just use these to reflect the accuracy of the current signal, or if necessary, try to deduce whether it's fine or coarse from these values.